# Published Vb.net project not running

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm using visual studio 19, published a project of mine by using the default pushing tool in the solution properties. I have added; file.exe.deploy, file.exe.manifest, file.pdb.deploy and System.Data.SQLite.dll.deploy.
But when I run the main .exe file after installation nothing happens.

Comment: Looks like there is a not managed error at application opening, I would start by checking the event viewer and Performance manager / Disk to see if you can find a log or an error message to start with.

Comment: @Amoah Rexford Gyamfi Not sure if you solved the question have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541888/setup-file-failing-debugging-enabled